# Wpf canvas refresh

Tags: wpf, canvas, refresh

I'm wondering if there is a way to refresh canvas before adding a child item to it?
I have this code, it draw me a black ellipse with light blue stroke. Now I want to change StrokeThickness when program is launched (I have a slider to define StrokeThickness). The problem is that StrokeThickness is changed but only if I redraw ellipse, but I want that change is made when I move my slider. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
            //this code is in canvas_MouseDown
            double smt = sliderThickness.Value;

            //krog
            elip = new Ellipse
            {
                Width = 100,
                Height = 100,
                Fill = Brushes.Black,
                Stroke = Brushes.LightBlue,
                StrokeThickness = smt,
            };

            Canvas.SetLeft(elip, mouseX - 50);
            Canvas.SetTop(elip, mouseY - 50);

            canvas1.Children.Add(elip);
```

Comment: That should work without "refresh". Just add the Ellipse *once* and only change the StrokeThickness of the existing Ellipse afterwards.

Comment: But how do i acess to existing Ellipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or shorter

```
// using System.Linq;

foreach (var ellipse in canvas1.Children.OfType<Ellipse>())
{
    ellipse.StrokeThickness = sliderThickness.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in slider value Changedevent u have to put following code

```
 private void sliderThickness_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        foreach (var item in canvas1.Children)
        {
            if (item is Ellipse)
            {
                var elip = item as Ellipse;
                elip.StrokeThickness = sliderThickness.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```